# In R, I have a data frame with no columns and would like to split it into different columns

Tags: r, database

I am writing a script that goes into our machine and parses a trace file which is a txt file. I am grepping for a particular value, in this example, "RP", and creating a dataframe from that data. Now I have all these rows, but no columns. I would want to split in columns. Here is how it looks like after the grep.

1   2016-03-14 09:52:38> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0004

What I would want is...
Date                     Pressure
2016-03-14 09:52:38      rp+0004

```
options(warn=-1)
#Select Copy From Dir, Change \\ to /
copyfrom<-gsub("\\\\","/",choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Select folder you wish to copy files from"))
#File names
listfiles<-list.files(copyfrom)
#Total amount of files
totalfiles=length(listfiles)
#Select Copy To Dir, Change \\ to /
copyto<-gsub("\\\\","/",choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Select folder you wish to copy files to"))


#Loop through all files in direct
for (totalfiles in 1:totalfiles)
{
  #Opening the file based on how many files present
  con <- file(paste0(copyfrom,"/",listfiles[totalfiles]))
  #open connection to file
  open(con); 
  #read file
  read <- readLines(con) 
  #search file for particular value
  searched_entries = grep("RP", read, value = T)
  #write file, remove .trc from file name and add _parsed
  writeLines(searched_entries, con = paste0(copyto,"/",gsub(".trc","",listfiles[totalfiles]),"_parsed.txt"))
  #close connection and print total files parsed
  close(con)
  print(totalfiles)
}
```

Here is the data frame:

2016-03-14 09:52:38> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0004 2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0000 2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0000 2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0000 etc..

I would like to end up with a 2 columns, one with the date (2016-03-14 09:52:3) the other with RP number (rp+0000) Let me know if you would like me to clarify further.

Here is the Trace file. You can copy paste this into notepad and save it as a .txt file
Name of file: StarLineDailyMaintenance_8715f3804819481aae1cae3a479556aa_Trace.trc

2016-03-14 09:52:38> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0004
2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:40> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:40> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:40> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:41> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:41> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:41> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:42> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:42> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:42> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:43> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:43> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:43> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:44> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:44> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:45> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:45> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:45> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:46> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:46> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:46> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:47> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:47> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:47> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:48> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:48> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:48> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+0000
2016-03-14 09:52:49> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+4067
2016-03-14 09:52:50> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+4057
2016-03-14 09:52:50> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+4028
2016-03-14 09:52:51> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+4057
2016-03-14 09:52:52> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+4082
2016-03-14 09:52:52> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+4125
2016-03-14 09:52:53> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete;  > RP: rp+4082

Comment: Is the data frame really a single value without rows also? Or just a formatting issue?

Comment: Well what I want to do is import a txt file with data, and then format it into a  data array with columns and rows. Its similar to what excel does. You can go to a text importer in excel and define the data type as fixed length, and this will align into columns with spaces. This is what I would like to do with R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_match from stringr with a regex to parse the lines;

```
> library(stringr)

> df

#                                                                                               V1
# 1 2016-03-14 09:52:38> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0004 
# 2 2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0000 
# 3 2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0000 
# 4 2016-03-14 09:52:39> Microlab® STAR : Firmware Command (Single Step) - complete; > RP: rp+0000

> f <- as.data.frame(str_match(df$V1, '^([^>]*)>[^>]*> RP: ([^ ]*) *$')[,-1])
> colnames(f) = c('Date', 'Pressure')
> f

#                  Date Pressure
# 1 2016-03-14 09:52:38  rp+0004
# 2 2016-03-14 09:52:39  rp+0000
# 3 2016-03-14 09:52:39  rp+0000
# 4 2016-03-14 09:52:39  rp+0000
```

The somewhat complex looking regex basically grabs everything up to the first `>` to column 1, and everything efter `> RP:` to column 2.

Assuming the file is line feed separated with the format given, you could also just parse the data straight from the file using `read.pattern` from `gsubfn` with the same regex;

```
> library(gsubfn)

> f = read.pattern('Test/test.txt', '^([^>]*)>[^>]*> RP: ([^ ]*) *$')
> colnames(f) = c('Date', 'Pressure')
> f

#                  Date Pressure
# 1 2016-03-14 09:52:38  rp+0004
# 2 2016-03-14 09:52:39  rp+0000
# 3 2016-03-14 09:52:39  rp+0000
# 4 2016-03-14 09:52:39  rp+0000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.
I got this issue when trying to import the data.

f <- as.data.frame(str_match(df$V1, '^([^>]*)>[^>]*> RP: ([^ ]*) *$')[,-1])
Error in df$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @user2128119 What is the column name in your data frame where the unparsed string is stored?

Comment: My mistake, data was not a dataframe. I did this..
library(stringr)
searched_entries=data.frame(searched_entries)
searched_entries <- as.data.frame(str_match(df$V1, '^([^>]*)>[^>]*> RP: ([^ ]*) *$')[,-1])
colnames(searched_entries) = c('Date', 'Pressure')

but got this error: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Date", "Pressure")) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Also I noticed that, after you run this line: 
 f <- as.data.frame(str_match(df$V1, '^([^>]*)>[^>]*> RP: ([^ ]*) *$')[,-1])
It deletes everything from the table, there is nothing in it.

Comment: I dont think there was any column name. That is the problem. I am taking a txt file with no columns, and trying to make columns.

Comment: @user2128119 Added another option for reading straight from file if that helps. Otherwise I'd need some kind of reproducible input data to work from.

Comment: Is this a library?
 library(gsubfn)
it says there is none.

Comment: I included the input file but you will have to generate it on your on because I cannot attach.

Comment: @user2128119 If you don't already have `gsubfn`, just do `install.packages('gsubfn')`. When copying the data included to a file, read.pattern reads the file correctly into two columns.